# Error when trying to get class probabilities in R's caret package

Tags: r, r-caret

I found questions similar to this, but the didn't fix my problem: I use caret with the ranger method to fit a random forest, then use predict to predict my evaluation data. This works. But when I try to get the prediction probabilities, I get the following error:

> Error in [.data.frame(out, , obsLevels, drop = FALSE) :    undefined
>   columns selected

The code (an example)

```
require(caret)

mtcars$carb <- as.factor(mtcars$carb)

tuneGrid <- expand.grid(mtry = c(10), min.node.size = c(1), splitrule = "extratrees")
rf_model<-train(carb~.,data=mtcars,method="ranger",
                trControl=trainControl(method="none")
                , tuneGrid = tuneGrid
)

predict(rf_model, mtcars, type="prob")
```

I made sure that carb is a factor as suggested elsewhere.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a couple of issues.
First, this approach requires that the class levels of the factor follow the convention of valid
R variable names, so renaming the levels of the carb factor to start with a letter is the first step

```
mtcars$carb <- as.factor(paste0("c",mtcars$carb))
```

Second, the default argument of classProbs in TrainControl is set to `FALSE`.
This should be `TRUE` in your case.

```
library("caret")

tuneGrid <- expand.grid(mtry = c(10), min.node.size = c(1), splitrule = "extratrees")
rf_model <- train(carb ~ ., data = mtcars, method = "ranger",
              trControl = trainControl(method = "none", classProbs = TRUE),
              tuneGrid = tuneGrid)

classprobs <- predict(rf_model, newdata = mtcars, type = "prob")
```

Comment: The first one was an obvious mistake of mine, my actual dataset has valid factor names. The second was new to me and fixed it. Thanks!